# Construct a function exactly belongs to $H^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: derivatives, sobolev-spaces

Question: How to construct a function exactly belongs to $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ but does not belong to $H^{1+s}(\mathbb{R})$ for any $s>0$?

My try: An obviously try is $u(x)=|x|$. However, I find that $u(x)\in H^{1+1/2-\epsilon}(\mathbb{R})$ actually. Is there any way to find out this function? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f$ be the inverse Fourier transform of
$$\hat{f}(\xi) = \frac{\sqrt{2|\xi|}}{(1+\xi^2)\log(2 + 2\xi^2)}$$
Then
$$(1+ \xi^2)|\hat{f}(\xi)|^2 = \frac{2|\xi|}{(1+\xi^2)\log^2(2+2\xi^2)}
= - \text{sgn}(\xi)\frac{d}{d\xi}\left(\frac{1}{\log(2+2\xi^2)}\right)$$
It follows that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}(1+ \xi^2)|\hat{f}(\xi)|^2 d\xi = \frac{2}{\log(2)}$$
and for $s>0$
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}(1+ \xi^{2+2s})|\hat{f}(\xi)|^2 d\xi = +\infty$$
Hence $f\in H^1(\mathbb{R})$ but $f\notin H^{1+s}(\mathbb{R})$.

**Edit** As suggested by @TZakrevskiy in the comment, the same method gives a function that belongs to $H^s(\mathbb{R})$ but not to $H^{s+\epsilon}(\mathbb{R})$ for any $\epsilon>0$. One can choose
$$\hat{f}(\xi) = \sqrt{\frac{2|\xi|}{(1+\xi^{2s})(1+\xi^2)}}\frac{1}{\log(2 + 2\xi^2)}$$

Comment: If I understand correctly, the same method works if you want a function in $H^s$ which does not belong to $H^{s+\varepsilon}$.

Comment: Your answer is obviously right. However, we cannot get the implicit formula for $f$, right?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't think we can get easily a formula for $f$, apart from $\int_\mathbb{R} \hat{f}(\xi) e^{2 \pi i x \xi} d\xi$.

Answer (score 0):

Something like
$$
u(x) := \int_0^x \frac{e^{-t^2}}{\sqrt{|t|} \log |t|} \, dt 
$$
should do the work.